# QUnit isn't running manually namespaced setup code like I would expect?

Tags: javascript, qunit, chutzpah

In stuff.js:

```
function init() {
    return "works";
}

(function(ParentNamespace) {
    ParentNamespace.MySubNamespace = {};
})(window.MyNamespace || (window.MyNamespace = {}));
```

In my test JS file:

```
/// <reference path="../../../project1/Shared/sub1/Javascript/stuff.js" />
test("foo test", function () {
    deepEqual(init(), "works", "couldn't access source JS file");
    ok(window, "no window context");
    var ns = window.MyNamespace;
    ok(ns in window, "namespace is bad");
    var ns2 = window.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace;
    ok(ns2 in window, "subnamespace is bad");
});
```

I get `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.MyNamespace.MySubNamespace')` when running the above test using Chutzpah Test Adapter.  That is to say, an exception is thrown on the `var ns2` line, and I never get to the last `ok()` assertion.  What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't qUnit/Chutzpah have run the code in stuff.js before trying to run the test?

Comment: If I rewrite the function to be callable directly as foo, and then I call it with `foo(window.MyNamespace || (window.MyNamespace = {}));` before doing my assertions, I get "namespace is bad" and "subnamespace is bad". Doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the test. Following test works...

```
/// <reference path="../../../project1/Shared/sub1/Javascript/stuff.js" />
test("foo test", function () {
deepEqual(init(), "works", "couldn't access source JS file");
ok(window, "no window context");    
ok('MyNamespace' in window, "namespace is bad");    
ok('MySubNamespace' in window.MyNamespace, "subnamespace is bad");
});
```

Comment: OK, but why doesn't it work without the single quotes?  That is, why doesn't `ok(MyNamespace in window, "namespace is bad");` pass?

Comment: This is just a JavaScript syntax. Your question can be best replied by the authors of JavaScript :)

Comment: I would think the above is valid syntax.  `MyNamespace` is an object that should exist; `window` is an object that exists, and the `in` operator tests to see if the right side object is a member of the left side object.  What am I missing?

Comment: As mentioned earlier this is the syntax. The syntax is "propNameOrNumber in objectName" where propNameOrNumber is a string or numeric expression representing a property name or array index, and objectName is the name of an object.  Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: Got it--that's what I was missing.  Too bad "in" isn't a little more flexible.